# Why can't I get data from my NPGSQL server?

Tags: c#, .net, database, server, npgsql

I need to write a C# program and it has to be able to manage my data on my server. I have an NPGSQL server set up with a data table, I can write data into it, but I just can't get to read the data while running a program.What do I do wrong?

```
 public NpgsqlDataReader reader;
    public NpgsqlCommand InsertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand();
    public String sConnectionString;
    public Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection Conn;
    public void DataBaseOpen()
    {
        sConnectionString = "Server=192.168.1.100;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=admin;Database=analoginput;Pooling=false;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=999;Timeout=15;";

    Conn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(sConnectionString);

    InsertCommand = Conn.CreateCommand();
    Conn.Open();
    }

  public void DataBaseClose()
        {
        Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
        Conn.Close();
        }

InsertCommand.CommandText = "Select * From public.sensorlog WHERE \"date\" > '2019.07.08.' And \"date\" < '2019.07.10.' order by Date asc;";
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(InsertCommand.CommandText);
            Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader reader = InsertCommand.ExecuteReader();
            System.Data.DataTable CSV = new System.Data.DataTable();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                CSV.Load(reader);
            }
```

I want to load the data into the CSV datatable, but I just can't get it to work. The datatable is just empty.

Comment: Have you tried replacing your `WHERE` with a `LIMIT` to see if there's a problem with the date matching?

Comment: I used the exact same command in pgadmin query tool, and it works

Comment: Also, even if I delete all the limits, and my command is "SELECT * FROM public.sensorlog", the datatable stays empty

Comment: Remove the `;` inside the `CommandText` string, might not affect it - but it's not needed either

Comment: Still nothing, I just can't figure it out.. In the other program it worked just like charm

Comment: The example c# is not complete program. Are you not executing DatabaseOpen() Method. You could be throwing an exception and not seeing it. Try to enclose you executereader inside a try catch block and popup a messagebox in the catch block if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

What if you refactor your code to something like below.

The using statement will guarantee that your connection & command is closed/disposed when it goes out of scope and with the try/catch block you will catch any exceptions and report it to the UI via messagebox. This will assist in capturing exceptions if there are any.

```
public Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection DatabaseOpen()
{
    var sConnectionString = "Server=192.168.1.100;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=xxx;Database=analoginput;Pooling=false;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=999;Timeout=15;";

    var Conn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(sConnectionString);

    Conn.Open();

    return Conn;
}
public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = DatabaseOpen())
        {
            using (var InsertCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                InsertCommand.CommandText = "Select * From public.sensorlog WHERE \"date\" > '2019.07.08.' And \"date\" < '2019.07.10.' order by Date asc;";
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(InsertCommand.CommandText);
                Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader reader = InsertCommand.ExecuteReader();
                System.Data.DataTable CSV = new System.Data.DataTable();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CSV.Load(reader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
    finally
    {
        Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
    }
}
```